# Why is the intake of the 757 (RR) engine slanted?

Tags: turbofan, engine-design, inlet, boeing-757

I'm sitting looking at a 757 with Rolls-Royce engines and just noticed that the intake is slanted forward by 5-10 degrees. Anyone know why?

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TF-FIV_KEF_(36695305326).jpg))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case frequently, as the aircraft doesn’t have the same pitch angle on ground while accelerating, or at rotation, or at climb or at cruise. So the intake slant is calculated to the best appropriate as an average. As a summary this is not specific to this engine on this aircraft